# is there any way to calculate L2 norm of multiple 2d matrices at once, in python?

Tags: python, numpy

for example, I have a matrix of dimensions **(a,b,c,d)**. I want to calculate **L2** norm of all **d** matrices of dimensions **(a,b,c)**. Is there any way to use `numpy.linalg.norm` with out any looping structure?
I mean, the resultant array should be **1 x d**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
mat      = np.arange(2*3*4*5).reshape(2,3,4,5)  # create 4d array
mat2     = np.moveaxis(mat,-1,0)     # bring last axis to the front
*outarr, = map(np.linalg.norm,mat2)  # use map
```

Comment: Thanks man, very impressive answer. I just checked on my data, and the answer is correct. although the mapping step is bit hard for me to understand. thank you

Comment: Understand iterators and iterables. Then map will become clear.